# Can I use the Rust lexer or parser to retrieve a list of functions within a Rust file?

Tags: rust, lexer

The lexer/parser file located [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libsyntax/parse/lexer/mod.rs) is quite large and I'm not sure if it is suitable for just retrieving a list of Rust functions. Perhaps writing my own/using another library would be a better route to take?

The end objective would be to create a kind of execution manager. To contextualise, it would be able to read a list of function calls wrapped in a function. The function calls that are within the function will then be able to be re/ordered from some web interface. Thought it might be nice to manage larger applications this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. I mean, not *really*.  Whether you write your own parser or re-use [`syntex`](https://crates.io/crates/syntex), you're going to hit a fundamental limitation: *macros*.

So let's say you go all-out and expand `macro_rules!`-based macros, *including* the ones defined in external crates (which means you'll also need to extract `rustc`'s crate metadata loading... which isn't stable).  What about procedural macros and custom derive attributes?  Those are defined in code and depend on compiler-internal interfaces to function.

The only way this is likely to ever work *correctly* is if you build *on top* of the compiler, or duplicate a huge amount of work (which also involves unstable binary interfaces).

Comment: Hm, I didn't consider macros. Excluding macros though, would the `syntex` library be able just to get me just the functions in a file, including their start and end positions?

Comment: You could parse the source file into an AST, then walk the AST to find `fn` items, yes.  Keep in mind that you won't get *any* type information; `syntex` operates at a level before type (or even name) resolution is performed.  If whatever you're planning involves knowing the types involved, it might not be possible without building on top of the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [syntex](https://crates.io/crates/syntex) to parse the Rust code in a build script.